# why return different sequence of ip addresses?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ip

When I used nslookup to query google.com twice, I got same ip addresses but different order, why?
These are return:
    Server:     129.173.1.100
    Address:    129.173.1.100#53

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.169
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.160
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.161
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.162
Name:       google.com
Address: 74.125.226.163
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.164
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.165
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.166
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.167
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.168
```

second time:

```
Server:     129.173.1.100
Address:    129.173.1.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.167
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.168
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.169
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.174
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.160
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.161
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.162
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.163
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.164
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.165
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.226.166
```

Any reply will be really appreciated!!!

Comment: Round Robin DNS for load balancing. That is DNS 101 for beginners - and as such a question that should not be asked here.

Comment: Sorry, I did search this but not detailed explanation shown

Answer (score 1):

When you consider the main purpose of having multiple A records for a single name (ie:DNS Round Robin) is for load balancing purposes, it would make sense that the way most DNS servers will implement this is by rotating the records that are returned. **Most** applications will use the first record that is returned (even when multiple records are returned), so rotating the records basically preforms a round-robin load balancing function.